# How to map the File system inside container to work-space inside Visual Studio Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

I am using Visual Studio Code or vscode for editing files. I also use Mobaxterm for server connections sessions. 
We can map the directory file system of the server space to work space in the vscode using extension ftp-simple.
I have created a vault conatiner and want to map the file system inside the vault conatiner to the workspace inside vscode.
Any suggestion regarding an extension or support is welcome.

Comment: The big difference between a container and a remote server is that it’s very common to destroy the container and lose everything in its local filesystem.  In almost all cases you should prefer some other more persistent path to doing what you need.

Comment: Is it a feature yet to be added to vscode or docker itself?

Comment: By design of Docker, if you edit files directly inside of containers, you’re setting yourself up to lose work.  A reproducible `docker build` setup with config files injected from the host as needed is far better.  There’s nothing technically stopping an IDE from having the feature (Emacs does) but I don’t recommend it.

Comment: Have you tried mounting a volume?

Comment: Yes, i have mounted a persistent volume inside the container.